# CentOS kickstart raid 1 and LVM issues

Tags: centos7, kickstart, anaconda

While doing an unattended install of CentOS 7 using kickstart. I set two disks to me mirrored.

```
bootloader --location=mbr --driveorder=sda,sdb
zerombr
clearpart --all --initlabel 

# Disk partitioning
part raid.01 --fstype="raid" --ondisk=sda --size=500
part raid.02 --fstype="raid" --grow --ondisk=sda --size=1
part raid.03 --fstype="raid" --ondisk=sdb --size=500
part raid.04 --fstype="raid" --grow --ondisk=sdb --size=1

raid /boot --device=md0 --fstype="ext4" --level=1 raid.01 raid.03
raid pv.01 --device=md1 --level=1 raid.02 raid.04

volgroup VolGroup pv.01

logvol swap --vgname="VolGroup" --size=4096 --name="lv_swap"
logvol / --vgname="VolGroup" --size=1 --grow --name="lv_root" --fstype="ext4"
```

During the install anaconda throws the error: `ValueError("not enough free space in volume group")`

I'm using CentOS 7.0.1406.

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug in `python-blivet` and was fixed upstream and is no longer an issue with CentOS 7.1 (1503).

Bug References:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1120339

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1093144

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=73883